# PayPal & Webhooks

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions, paypal-webhooks

Through REST API, I create Plans and I can create Agreements for subscriptions (recurring payments).

(As a general observations: PayPal should also allow plans to be created in the developer sandbox/live)

When creating an agreement, I use the Seller oAuth2 token (versus the Member's Token)

Webhooks set to 'All' in the developer account, testing OK, simulation OK.

However, when events (https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/rest-webhooks-overview/#event-type-support) occur I don't receive notifications.

QUESTION:

- Am I doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Selecting "All" webhooks does not imply notification for all events related to PayPal. Selecting that will subscribe you to all current and all future events.

Right now none of the current event supports "Subscription Events". We would be rolling out support for them in future, and if you have selected "All events" as Webhook event type, your Webhook would be subscribed to them automatically.

Comment: Many thanks.
Some feedback: It would be helpful if this info will be captured in the documentation as well.

Comment: Subscription Webhooks are live. !! https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/rest-webhooks-overview/#event-type-support

Comment: BILLING.SUBSCRIPTION.SUSPENDED: This event is triggered when a billing subscription is suspended.  
BILLING.SUBSCRIPTION.RE-ACTIVATED: This event is triggered when a billing subscription is reactivated.  
BILLING.SUBSCRIPTION.CANCELLED: This event is triggered when a billing subscription is cancelled.

Comment: Tested - webhook events OK. One observation: if member cancels agreement from own account no event is sent. Not critical but an upgrade will be nice.

Comment: Sure, we are continuously working on the feedback. Pls describe the scenario in detail, isnt the cancel event covered via Billing Subscription Cancelled ? Also Pls accept the answer if it solves your issue.

Comment: The scenario: if a member decides to cancel the subscription, a member has two choices:

1) can access own account and cancel it. -> an event should be triggered, so that the member's account is closed due to non-payment

2) can cancel the subscription through the application -> subscription can be cancelled through REST calls. Tested and working well.